# Java- "symbol not found"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm new to java and I have a pretty common compiling error. I tried other solutions, but nothing worked for me. I have to create a calendar, here is a snippet frm my Date.java:

```
package edu.kit.informatik.calendar;
public final class Date {

private final int year; // Placeholder value
private final int month; // Placeholder value
private final int day; // Placeholder value

public int dayOfYear;

public Date(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
    this.year  = year;
    this.month  = month;
    this.day  = dayOfMonth;
}   
public DateTime atTime(Time time){
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(this, time);
    return dateTime;
}
public int getYear(){
    return year;
}
public int getMonthValue(){
    return month;
}
public int getDayOfMonth(){
    return day;
}   
public int getMonth(){
    return Month.ofIndex(month);
}
```

In another file called DateTime.java i have something like this:

```
package edu.kit.informatik.calendar;

public final class DateTime {

private final Date date; // Placeholder value
private final Time time; // Placeholder value

public DateTime(Date date, Time time){
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

public Date getDate(){
    return date;
}
public Time getTime(){
    return time;
}

public int getYear(){
    return date.getYear();
}
public int getMonthValue(){
    return date.getMonthValue();
}
public Month getMonth(){
    return date.getMonth();
}
public int getDayOfYear(){
    return date.getDayOfYear();
}
public int getDayOfMonth(){
    return date.getDayOfMonth();
}
public int getHour(){
    return time.getHour();
}
public int getMinute(){
    return time.getMinute();
}
public int getSecond(){
    return time.getSecond();
}

public String toString(){
    return date.toString() + "T" + time.toString();
}
}
```

Then there is another file called Time.java, but it just looks like the other two.

When I try to compile the DateTime.java

```
C:\Users\Marcel\Documents\Programmieren\assignment01-     solution\TaskE\edu\kit\informatik\calendar>javac DateTime.java
DateTime.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
private final Date date; // Placeholder value
              ^
symbol:   class Date
location: class DateTime
DateTime.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    private final Time time; // Placeholder value
                  ^
  symbol:   class Time
location: class DateTime
DateTime.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
      public DateTime(Date date, Time time){
                      ^
  symbol:   class Date
  location: class DateTime
DateTime.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        public DateTime(Date date, Time time){
                        ^
  symbol:   class Time
  location: class DateTime
DateTime.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        public Date getDate(){
               ^
  symbol:   class Date
  location: class DateTime
  DateTime.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        public Time getTime(){
               ^
symbol:   class Time
location: class DateTime
DateTime.java:33: error: cannot find symbol  
    public Month getMonth(){
           ^
symbol:   class Month
location: class DateTime
7 errors
```

Comment: You presumably haven't compiled your `Date` class. Pass both to `javac`, or even better, use an IDE.

Comment: As is said, I none if these could solve my Problem.

Comment: @MarcelM.  Correction - one of them would .... but you can't figure out which of the many possible problems / solutions matches yours.

Comment: Let's say it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't know anything about your Date class when you are trying to compile DateTime.java. You need to compile them both if one uses the other:

```
javac DateTime.java Date.java
```

Comment: I get this as a return: javac: invalid flag: Date.class

Comment: I was compling a .class instdt of a .java. When I compiled 5 files at once it worked. Thanks buddy!

Comment: But do I have to compile all the files together from now on?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a classpath / buildpath problem.  Since you haven't set $CLASSPATH and you didn't use a `-cp` option, you should be in the `TaskE` directory when compiling.

Or (as @chryslis says) use an IDE or a build tool like Maven or Ant to do your building, and remove the unpredictability of typing `javac` commands by hand.

Comment: When I'm in the /taskE directory, the cmd tells me that he cannot find the file.

Comment: Then give the path of the file relative to where you are!

Comment: But what does it change, when I'm in the directory of the file, or I gove the path?

Comment: Trust me.  Try it.   Then read the "javac" manual entry about how it finds source files for classes that haven't been compiled (yet).